# JavaScript Canvas Download

Tags: javascript, html, file, canvas

I have a problem downloading my drawing from a canvas. This is my code:

```
    function downloadCanvas(link, canvasId, filename) {
    link.href = document.getElementById(canvasId).toDataURL();
    const le = link.href;
    console.log(le);
    le.download = filename;
};
download.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    downloadCanvas(this, 'draw', 'Drawing.jpeg');
}, false);
```

The console show the value of `le`, which is the link to download, but the file isn't downloaded... What is wrong here? I'm a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is you're attempting to download a link location, whereas you simply need to be downloading the link file.

To fix this, you should change the `const le = link.href;` to `const le = link;`. However, you might as well just get rid of the `const le` and change `le.download` to `link.download`.

Hope that helps!

**Edit:**

Here's a cleaned up version of the code:

```
function downloadCanvas(link, canvasId, filename) {
    link.href = document.getElementById(canvasId).toDataURL();
    link.download = filename;
};
download.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    downloadCanvas(this, 'draw', 'Drawing.jpeg');
}, false);
```

Comment: You could just post the amended code, its really short and might help the OP a lot to see a cleaned up version of his code that actually works.

Comment: Now you might just want to click to link to initiate it... Although I could be wrong on that, I think browsers block it if the link isn't attached to the dom. Personally, I would also change `mousedown` to `click`, but thats pedantic. +1